# TypeError: Cannot read property 'username' of undefined discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Whenever I run this command i got this error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined`

I think error is here: `let member = message.mentions.members.first()`
But why?

Here is my userinfo command:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'profile',
    description: 'Get the profile of the tagged user, or your own profile.',
    execute(message, args) {
        let member = message.mentions.members.first() // any (why?)
        const msapr = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // Профиль автора сообщения
        .setColor ('0x0099ff')
        .setTitle ('Профиль участника ' + message.author.username)
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Ник:', value: `${message.author}` },
            { name: 'ID:', value: message.author.id }
        )
        .setThumbnail(message.author.avatarURL())
        const mmupr = new Discord.MessageEmbed() // Профиль упомянутого пользователя
            .setColor ('0x0099ff')
            .setTitle ('Профиль участника ' + member.user.username)
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Ник:', value: `${member}` },
                { name: 'ID:', value: member.user.id }
            )
            .setFooter (message.author.username, message.author.avatarURL())
            .setThumbnail(member.user.avatarURL())
        if (!message.mentions.users.size) {
            return message.channel.send(msapr);
        }
        message.channel.send(mmupr)
    },
};
```

The error :

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\Кирилл\Documents\Дискорд боты\crazy-bot\commands\profile.js:17:45)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Кирилл\Documents\Дискорд боты\crazy-bot\index.js:175:11)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\Кирилл\Documents\Дискорд боты\crazy-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\Кирилл\Documents\Дискорд боты\crazy-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\Кирилл\Documents\Дискорд боты\crazy-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\Кирилл\Documents\Дискорд боты\crazy-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\Кирилл\Documents\Дискорд боты\crazy-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Кирилл\Documents\Дискорд боты\crazy-bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:125:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:315:20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the [username](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username) property of a [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember) object. But it doesn't exist. You'll have to get thro' the [User](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) object if you want to access the [username](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=username). Change

```js
            .setTitle ('Профиль участника', user.username)
```

to

```js
            .setTitle ('Профиль участника', user.user.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your user init by renaming it to member, then go for `member.displayName`or `member.user.username` instead of `user.username`, because your user is not a real user but a member.
See [GuildMember](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember)